# Can't re-build in Netbeans 7.0

Tags: java, netbeans

I've been trying lately to re-build my project so I can update my executable on my desktop, but for some reason it's failing to build the project showing this error:

```
    Updating property file: F:\JDA\CalculatorMedii\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory F:\JDA\CalculatorMedii\build
F:\JDA\CalculatorMedii\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1019: Unable to delete file F:\JDA\CalculatorMedii\dist\CalculatorMedii.jar
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I tried deleting the file manually, but that gave another error. I restored it. Any idea how to fix this? I should also mention that my project is 100% clean with no errors in the code, and I can run it through NetBeans anytime. The only problem is when I try to rebuild or build&clean it shows that error.

Also I'm using NetBeans 7.0.1

PROBLEM FIXED. Restarting netbeans then building solved this.

Comment: what error you got when you delete file manually ?

Comment: the only thing yo have to do is stop your glassfish server before making the clean and build. Glassfish is the one that blocks the file.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to restart the IDE in these cases.  The file is being held open by glassfish.  Go to the "Services" tab, select the Glassfish server, and then select stop on the right click menu.  It will be restarted automatically next time you run your project.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the jar file in dist directory should solve the problem. What is the error you are getting if you delete the jar file?

Comment: Problem has been fixed. Restarting netbeans then building the project was enough to fix the problem.

Comment: aware the server are still running. i used to experience the problem because the server are running so it not able to clean.. try to stop then again clean&build will success. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue with netbeans and windows because windows won't let you delete a file in use. I had to stop the server then clean and build.